# Laravel5.6 - after validation form fail, how to set up variable from parent view

Tags: laravel, view

i have a view named ('back.employee.detail') with an @includewhen('back.dossiers.create') into it.

my div for error is in 'back.employee.detail' :

```
<div class="alert {{ $type_alert }} alert-dismissible">

<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria hidden="true">×</button>
        <h4><i class="icon fa {{ $alert_icon }}"></i> Alert!</h4>
        {{ $flash_message }}
</div>
```

my form is in my view 'back.dossiers.create' and inside i use $employee_detail :

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('create.document.employee.store',  $employee_detail->id) }}" aria-label="{{ __('Create') }}">
    @csrf
    <div class="box-body">

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="description">Description</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control {{ $errors->has('description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                   name="description" id="description" value="{{ old('description') }}">

            @if ($errors->has('description'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('description') }}</strong>
                    </span>
            @endif

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="commentaire">Commentaire</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('commentaire') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}"
                   name="commentaire" id="commentaire" value="{{ old('commentaire') }}">

            @if ($errors->has('commentaire'))
                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('commentaire') }}</strong>
                    </span>
            @endif
        </div>

    </div>
    <!-- /.box-body -->

    <div class="box-footer">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

For validation error, i used to have that in my controller :

```
   return back()->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput()
            ->with('flash_message',$flash_message)
            ->with('type_alert',$type_alert)
            ->with('alert_icon',$alert_icon)
            ->with('type_crud',$type_crud)
            ->with('employee_detail',$employee_detail);
```

but the variable flash_message , type_alert... are into the parent view.

i want to update value for flash_message,type_alert,alert_icon,employee_detail and also type_crud and employee_detail but flash message has not been updated.

Do you have an idea how to do it ?

Thanks

Comment: not sure what you are asking

Comment: Please edit your answer and include the code from your view.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is't very clear to me.
Maybe this examples will help you a bit:

Pass data using includeWhen:

```
@includeWhen($boolean, 'view.name', ['some' => 'data'])

@include('view.name', ['some' => 'data'])
```

Hope this helps.
Gut luck:)

Comment: 0
down vote
accept
thank you for your reply. I know how to pass argument throught @includewhen.

at the line : return back()->withErrors($validator)

the back(), i think, redirect me to the last page opened. so i updated value with

`->with('flash_message',$flash_message)
            ->with('type_alert',$type_alert)
            ->with('alert_icon',$alert_icon)
            ->with('type_crud',$type_crud)
            ->with('employee_detail',$employee_detail);`
the trouble is the type_alert,alert_icon,type_crud has not been updated.